# selling single digital files in wordpress-based website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've seen some websites which in addition to having product with a total price, they have also defined separate prices for each single file of that product and customer can buy a single file.
for example the sell php video training package with the price of X  and it is also possible to buy each single file with its own price separately !
i don't think they have created each single file as a product in woocommerce, since there would be hundreds of products.
i don't know but i guess there may be a plugin for this.
how we can do that via woocommerce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add variations and attribute as first create a attribute name example a part in part create attribute as part1 part 2 than goto product page there you can find attribute add there part and in down side button add all so all part will be added  than click on used for variation checkbox now update it once u have done this in variation tab from drop down select part and click on go 
Now u will find out all part so u can expand it an add whatever price u required ... 
[image: CHECK THIS 1 step]
[image: second step]